# Regular expression removing a line from multiline text

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have a regular expression

```
select regexp_replace('123@gmail.com - work new address',
                      [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}, '')
  from dual;
```

which i'm using to match email addresses. Some strings are stored as multilines

I want to match the email address on the 1st line and remove all text inlcuding - work, but NOT the second line after the carriage return.

Comment: regex `^.*?([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}).*` replace with `$1`

Comment: Where do i need to place the $1?

Comment: see regex_replace func in doc..

Comment: I've checked the docs, it doesn't say where to place the backreference

Answer (score 1):

First you must replace carriage return with a caracter like #.
For example :

```
REPLACE(yourstring,CHR(10),'#')
```

After with result string like "123@gmail.com -     work#new@address" you can execute this :

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr('123@gmail.com -     work#new@address',
'[^#]+', 1, level),'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]  {2,4}') 
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('123@gmail.com - work#new@address', 
                         '[^#]+',1,   level) is not null;


REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('123
--------------------------------
123@gmail.com
new@address
```

Comment: You should change your regex to `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}` ( escaping the dot outside the character classes ). Otherwise, `123@gmail.com work` will match as well.